# Javascript if document contains alert

Tags: javascript, document, contains

So I'm doing a quiz.And i want to check if || while document contains alert.So if the document contains alert then i want to append my Button Next.So this is my idea:

```
if(document.contains(alert)) {
            const buttonNext = document.createElement("button")
            buttonNext.innerText = "Next"
        } else {
            !document.append(buttonNext)
        }
```

This is the quiz section:

```
const myBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.Btn')
myQuestionAndAnswers.forEach(item => {
    const myAnswers = item.Answers
    const myQuestion = item.Question
    const mySecondStage = item.SecondStage
    myFunctionForOptions(myAnswers , myQuestion)
})

function myFunctionForOptions(answers, question) {
   const [firstObj, secondObj] = answers // ES6 definening 2 Object in one const variable
   let j
   const remainder = 30 % answers.length + 2
   console.log(remainder)
   for(j = 0;j < (myBtns.length / answers.length + remainder);j++) { //Replacing my Buttons with j
       const typeOfInput = myBtns[j].getAttribute('value') // Getting the value of the input
      myBtns[j].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          console.log(e.target)
        if(firstObj.option == typeOfInput) { //Checking if the firstObj is the same as the value of the input
        const myTrueAnswer = alert('Hey you got the answer right.Congratulations!')
        } else {
         const myFalseAnswer = alert('You got the answer wrong try next time...')
        }
```

Comment: What's your question? What's not working?

Comment: why would `document` contain `alert` - i.e. what code results in `document` gaining or losing the property called `alert`? - also, what do you think `!document.append(buttonNext)` does?

Comment: yeah i forgot to delete that!document.append(buttonNext), but in case that ur asking it means document do not append buttonNext

Comment: Well my idea is that if the document contains alert from myBtns[j] then i want to append that button to my div